# Coldfusion EntityLoad get methods not found but when using EntityLoadByPK the get methods work

Tags: mysql, database, coldfusion

I am building a web application on coldfusion 2016, for far everything works fine, but when I use entityload and try retrieving the adminID usin getAdminID() method, i get an error message, saying that the getAdminID method does not exist. However, when I use GetComponentMetadata(), I see all the Entity methods. Please see the codes and the image below:

```
<CFSCRIPT>
ORMReload();
showAdmin=getComponentMetadata("cfc.tbladmin");
</CFSCRIPT>
<cfdump var="#showAdmin#">
```

[image]

but when I try calling the method getAdminID(), I get the error the method does not exists. see the error and image below:

```
<CFSCRIPT>
ORMReload();
admin=entityload("tbladmin").getAdminID();
</CFSCRIPT>
<cfdump var="#admin#" >
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please dump what `entityload` returns without calling `.getAdminID()`?

Comment: Please see the error Image attached as a link.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NmF2.png

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because when you call `entityLoad` it gives you back a collection of all the objects in that table. More specifically, an array of all the entities. So, calling `entityload("tbladmin").getAdminID()` is not going to work because you're trying to call `.getAdminID()` on an array.

You have to loop through all the entities and call `.getAdminID()` on each of the individual entities. Try something like this:

```
<cfscript>
   var adminEnts = entityLoad("tbladmin");
   for (var adminEnt in adminEnts) {
       writeDump(adminEnt.getAdminID());
   }
</cfscript>
```